# Java Regex find all matches with ability to skip pattern groups

Tags: java, regex

I have this code that is supposed to find all the matches:

```
String pattern = "(?<controller>[a-z\\-]+)?(?<method>(/)?[a-z\\-]+)?";
    String url = "string";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(url);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("controller: " + m.group("controller"));
        System.out.println("method: " + m.group("method")+"\n");
    }
```

This is what I get:

```
controller: string
method: null

controller: null
method: null
```

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
controller: string
method: null

controller: null
method: string
```

I understand that as soon as regex detects a match it stops, so that's why the second group isn't matched even though it should potentially match.

Anybody has an idea how to achieve this?

Maybe I could somehow make the matcher skip the first group in the second iteration.

Essential example:

When I have two optional groups in the patter that both matches string of characters like this:

```
(\\w+)?(\\w+)?
```

Can I somehow iteratively match it against a string looking like this:

```
someValue
```

So in the first iteration it would match to group number 1
And in the second iteration it would match to group number 2

Comment: Can you add few more examples to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to match the same substring in two different ways. That's not how `find` works. It doesn't backtrack to find the next match, but looks for it after the previous match. Perhaps a regex is not the right tool here.

Comment: Your pattern does not look right since all the parts of it are optional. It is not clear what the requirements here are. I suspect all you need is split the string with `/`. `(\\w+)?(\\w+)?` does not make sense, all text will land in Group 1 as it is greedy.

Comment: Yes I know that it works like this. But I'm looking for a way how to skip groups.

Comment: You cannot "skip  groups". Skipping mean "not matching". Skipping while matching (like dropping the match and restarting with the match end position) is only possible in PCRE with `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs. Provide a comprehensive  set of real life examples with expected outputs, and we'll try to come up with a comprehensive solution.

Comment: Fair enough, I gave it a thought and came up with an alternative solution at the end. Thanks a lot for your help.